# How to create a function using UIButton instance as a parameter in a UIButton extension in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have some UIButton instances(buttons) and also wants to add a disclosure indicator to each of them. Therefore, I want to create a helper function. However, I don't know how to do that using an UIButton instance as a parameter in the UIButton extension. Following is the code I currently have.

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkByDepartment: DesignableButton!

let disclosure = UITableViewCell()
disclosure.frame = checkByDepartment.bounds
disclosure.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
disclosure.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

checkByDepartment.addSubview(disclosure)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you directly creating a table cell this way? This is most likely wrong.

Comment: The cell part is weird in your code snippet, are you trying to add a cell into the custom button?!

Comment: I wanna put an ios "native" disclosure indicator at the right of a button